# Why shouldn't I I ever compile header files (C++)?

Tags: c++

**My question is about header files. Why shouldn't I ever compile header files (C++)?**

Comment: The only time they are not is when they are passed as source which are ment to be used as header only libraries to include in your own code.  Which then get compiled.

Comment: If you have a large, complicated header, or a large number of headers, [sometimes you DO want to compile them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) to speed build times.

Answer (score 1):

Header files are compiled all the time, since they are included in translation units that you *should* compile.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between something called a ‘header file’ and something called ‘code file’ is exclusively that header files are to be included into code files.

In other words, a header file that needs to be compiled is not a header file *by definition*, but a code file.